# Upgrade Owl Carousel, Camera Slider in Opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, opencart2.x, owl-carousel-2

i updated my files of Owl Carousel v.1.3.2 to new version v2.3.4 to enable new features. after replacing files other product carousel modules working good. But Camera Slider module is not working, tried everything but it only runs with his old files.
Check Website: Indiazaade.com

Here is camera sliders file, which is quite simple.

```
<div class="camera_wrap2_<?php echo $slider['id']; ?>" id="">
       <?php foreach($slider['content'] as $sliders) {
            if($sliders[$language_id]['status'] == 1) { 
                $link = false;
                $image = $sliders[$language_id]['slider'];
                
                if($sliders[$language_id]['link'] != '') {
                    $link = $sliders[$language_id]['link'];
                } ?>
                <div class="items"><?php if($link) { echo '<a href="' . $link . '">'; } ?><img src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Slider"><?php if($link) { echo '</a>'; } ?></div>
        <?php   }
        } ?>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var camera_slider = $(".camera_wrap2_<?php echo $slider['id']; ?>");
          camera_slider.owlCarousel({
              items : 1,
        nav:true,
              responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:1
            },
            1000:{
                items:1
            }
        }
               });
    </script>
```

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with it, bcoz if other modules can works well, what is problem happening.
Really Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? what errors in your error log file?

Comment: i checked, but didn't recognize. Can you check- http://indiazaade.com/

Comment: just below menu is slider and then Deal of the day-product slider, which works well.

Comment: payment_2.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
payment_1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
payment_3.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
payment_4.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
payment_5.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Does this images related to your slider?

Comment: no related to slider. Actually it is quite unreal that below slider with same configuration works well.
Can you imagine what can be wrong, becoz this camera slider works well with old files.
I mean How?

Comment: Okay, i got a strange solution. For some reason selected element ( camera_slider.owlCarousel({ ----....----- }) ) to be carousel don't have owl-carousel class.
After adding it already from file it start working. 

Can you guess any reason not to have .Owl-carousel in it?